# UI tests on each Fragment Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, testing, android-espresso

I'd like to start implementing UI Tests on each of My Fragments. I just have some Math formulas to verify in each Fragment. 
Let's say that from Fragment A I have to go to Fragment B and then to Fragment C(I want to test if each of Fragment's C EditText text changes if a certain button gets clicked).
I Would like to don't go throughout all of the passages to arrive to Fragment C.
 I've already installed Espresso using Gradle, but what to do After? Please provide a Step by step implementation.
Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27370190/7861694
Or/If you using Espresso I recommend the second option -  add a unique id for one element in your fragment layout. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.id.html